# How to navigate Windows Libraries on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, file-structure

I need to recover the photos from a Windows 7 partition (Windows has been erased) external on a laptop running Ubuntu from a live USB stick. But I am not familiar with the Windows 7 file structure. I accidentally found a folder called Libraries containing all the photos. But now I don't seem to be able to find it again. I understand it is a virtual folder. How do I go about navigating to it again? I have tried systematically going through all the folders; I did find a folder called Libraries, but it is not the same as the one I found earlier on. 
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You'll find the default location for images is C:\Users\<username>\Photos

Comment: Doesn't work here. There's no photos directory there. There are pictures directories elsewhere on the drive, but with nothing in them.

Comment: The trouvle is, Windows uses symbolic links inside the diretories, so the files are not there to be copied.,